# How can my Slack Bot that uses Google APIs to generate a Google Sheet with data for users using a Service account add a Script to that sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-apps-script-api

I  have a private Slack Bot that uses Google APIs to generate a Google Sheet with data for our users.  I am using a Service account as the bot creates those sheets under it's own Google account.

Now I want to add a script to that sheet (so that users can upload the modified data back into the server) using the Google Script API.

How can I do this? What are the workarounds?

Comment: You can always use your own account or create a separate account for this purpose

Comment: Wouldnt a user be required to authenticate through a frontend manually?  How can a server side bot do it?